# Visual Studio Code, how to get a parent directory of current file in tasks

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to create a task to run a `sass` compilation for the current file but I'm not able to set the output `css` folder and filename.
The structure of my sass and css files are:

`myfolder\css\myfile.css`
`myfolder\scss\myfile.scss`

My current task is:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile SCSS",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "command": "sass --load-path ${workspaceFolder}\\vendor\\scss --load-path ${workspaceFolder}\\base\\scss --no-cache --sourcemap=none --update ../scss/${fileBasename}:${fileDirname}/../css/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.css"
        }
    ]
}
```

the problem is the latest section where I need to put my sass folder/file : my css folder/file
What's the approach here?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `${fileDirname}/` after the `:`?

Comment: Without that I'm getting `error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../scss/my-component.scss`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64760172/836330 A new variable is being added to address this: `${fileDirnameBasename}`