# is there any way to splitting Variables in VSCode?

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, split, parent

I wonder there is any way to splitting some variables in VSCode?

my example will explain my question better:

I have an `exe` file in such path `C:\path\to\workspace\main\project\project.exe`

my `cpp` source path that will create `exe` file is this `C:\path\to\workspace\main\project\test.cpp`

I want to create a `task` in `tasks.json` but my oder of variables does not give me the right path

as you understand:
`${workspaceFolder}` is `C:\path\to\workspace`

`${fileDirname}` returns `C:\path\to\workspace\main\project`

and `${relativeFileDirname}.exe` returns `main\project.exe`

and combination of `"${fileDirname}\\${relativeFileDirname}.exe"` as a command will return `C:\path\to\workspace\main\project\main\project.exe` that is wrong.

so I wanted to know there is any other variable that just return the `parent` of current `file` or not?

if `not` can we split variables with `\` ?

I hope it makes some sense

thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Add new fileDirnameBasename variable

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/551db7ec94f02a4bdc8999092cf8bef642b3992d

`${fileDirnameBasename}` is being added to vscode v1.52 which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

Use the commands:

- `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename`
- `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename1Up`
- `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename2Up`

Answer (score 0):

btw, as an workaround, this worked for me

`"${fileDirname}\\*.exe"`

but need a variable for getting parent folder of current open file

any idea?